# PHP is sending a blank form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am brand new to PHP so im sure theres something simple im missing. Below is the form on my site and the PHP code used to grab, its sending the right format to my email but all inputs are empty.

```
<form action="backyard/php/contact-form.php" id="contactForm" type="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </span>
                                        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Your Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </span>
                                        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Street Address, City, and Zip" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                         <div class="input-group">
                                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </span>
                                        <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                                             <div class="input-group">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" value="GET YOUR FREE REPORT" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
$email = $_post['email'] ;
$name = $_post['name'] ;
$company = $_post['company'] ;

    /* Set e-mail recipients */
    $to = 'codyg@calculatedservices.ca';

    // subject
    $subject = "Message from " .$name. " - Calculated | Contact form";

    // html message
    $body = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body
                {
                    font-family:sans-serif;
                }
                p
                {
                    font-size:16px;
                    color:rgb(12,12,12);
                }
                h1
                {
                    font-size:16px;
                    color:rgb(0,64,102);
                }
                .bg-color
                {
                    background: rgb(245,245,245);
                    border-radius:8px;
                }
                .bg-color2
                {
                    background:rgb(0,64,102);
                    color:white;font-size:16px;
                    border-radius:8px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table class="bg-color" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8px" width="480" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background:rgb(0,64,102);border-radius:8px;color:white;">
                        HELLO CALCULATED SERVICES
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="48" width="100%">
                        <p style="margin-top:20px;">Thank you from:</p>
                        <h1>'.$user_name.'</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bg-color2">
                        Company: <b>'.$company.'</b><br>
                        Name: <b>'.$name.'</b><br>
                        Email: <b>'.$email.'</b><br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    ';
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= "From: " .$email. "\r\n";

    // MAIL IT!
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($success) 
    {
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    } 
    else
    {
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }
    header ("location: http://www.lestwarog.com")
```

?>

Comment: Are you using the same script to display the form and send the email?

Comment: Change form "type" to "method". <form ...... method="post">

Comment: The moderators linking to other questions and answers, those don't answer the very simple issue that Cody is having with his code.

Comment: Changed type to method but no effect, still sending me an email formatted correctly but not grabbing the information from the form.

Comment: $_POST is case sensitive. I didn't notice it until just now. $_post won't work, while $_POST will.

Comment: So simple, that worked, thanks so much.